# The town of Concentric

Tags: mathematics, optimization, network

[image]

Here you see a water map of the town of Concentric. There are eight channels that run from the central boathouse of the city in a star shape.

There are three canals that lie concentric around the central boathouse.
There is one-way traffic on the channels, indicated by the green arrows.
On the canals you can sail both ways ; you cannot turn halfway ; at a crossing of a canal you may turn.

Every piece of a channel from boathouse to the first canal or from canal to canal has a length of 4.
Each piece of canal from channel to channel has a length of 3 (inner canal),
6 (middle canal) or 9 (outer canal).

From the central boathouse you have to deliver six packages, at the addresses indicated with the red triangles. Then you have to return to the central boathouse.

Specify the length of the shortest route you can take to return all packages as an answer.

Comment: This puzzle is a little confusing since it seems like you're using the word "canal" as if it were two different words, and expecting us to be able to distinguish between them. For example, you write that the canals have one-way traffic, whereas the canals have two-way traffic. You also write that segments of a canal have length 4, whereas segments of a canal have length 3, 6, or 9. It's quite confusing, and this puzzle would be much less confusing if you used different words for those two concepts.

Comment: When you say you can turn at a crossing, can you U-turn?

Answer (score 7):

This is a travelling salesman problem, so it's difficult to prove an answer, but using heuristics and no computer I found a path of length 91.

> Depart the hub heading Z, directions are then defined as (R)imward, (H)ubward, (C)lockwise, and (W)iddershins
>
> ```
> Path is RRRCHWWWRWHHWWWRCHH
> Cost is 4449466649443334644
> ```

Comment: I think you got C and T ( or should that be W) confused.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thanks, sorry, C was supposed to be a late replacement for T (C)lockwise for (T)urnwise, but I accidentally replaced W instead.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a graph with nodes labeled as follows:
[image]

This is not TSP because not every node needs to be visited.  Instead, it is a directed [rural postman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_routing#Rural_postman_problem) (with depot node $0$) for which the following arcs must be traversed (in one direction or the other):
[image]

Via subtour elimination, I found the following optimal solution, with length $$4+4+4+9+4+4+3+3+3+4+6+6+6+6+4+9+4+4+4=91$$
[image]

Here's an alternative optimal solution:
[image]